# Data scope within ethereum virtual machines

Tags: ethereum, solidity, evm

I would like to store some sensitive data within my contract in form of mapping

Using Solidity ^0.5

```
mapping(someKey => someStruct) someMap;
```

I'm aware of the privacy issue within smart contracts, the compiler automatically creates getter functions for all public state variables, but when it comes to mappings (or any dynamically sized variables), how can someone access them (by default), if not, is there any risk to reverse engineer the EVM in order to read the data.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Everything in a public blockchain is public. There's even an RPC method just to make reading a contract's storage easier: `eth_getStorageAt`. Another _contract_ can't directly read private state variables, but they're trivial to read from the outside.

Comment: @smarx thanks for your help, I would like to know if is there any risk to access data stored in form of mapping without having the key, I know otherwise it is impossible (this is why keys are made for) but by reverse engineering the EVM memory slots or any workaround, is it even possible to do so, as contracts are immutable which means EVMs should be not accessible

Comment: As I said, everything's public. For example, the transaction where you stored the data is public. Anyone can just read it and see what you stored and where.